# jQuery - How do i select these 'th' elements?

Tags: jquery, html, selector

I have my HTML structure like this:

```
<tbody id="tbodyCreateExpense">
    <tr>
        <th>Date(dd/mm/yy)</th>
        <th>Money(VND)</th>
        <th>Invoice ID</th>
        <th>Images</th>
        <th>Note</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="dataTR">
        <th class="es-cr-edit" data-attribute="date">
            <div><input class="datepicker" type="text" placeholder="11/11/2013"></div>
        </th>
        <th class="es-cr-edit" data-attribute="money">
            <div><input type="text"></div>
        </th>
        <th class="es-cr-edit" data-attribute="invoiceID">
            <div><input type="text"></div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div class="btn-end" data-attribute="invoiceImage">
                <a  href="#">Browse </a>
            </div>
        </th>
        <th class="es-cr-edit" data-attribute="note">
            <div><input type="text"></div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <figure class="iconsp-remove-25px"></figure>
            <figure class="iconsp-edit-25px"></figure>
        </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th class="es-cr-edit">
            <div><input class="datepicker" type="text" placeholder="11/11/2013"></div>
        </th>
        <th class="es-cr-edit">
            <div><input type="text"></div>
        </th>
        <th class="es-cr-edit">
            <div><input type="text"</div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div class="btn-end">
                <a  href="#">Browse </a>
            </div>
        </th>
        <th class="es-cr-edit">
            <div><input type="text"></div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <figure class="iconsp-remove-25px"></figure>
            <figure class="iconsp-edit-25px"></figure>
        </th>
    </tr>

</tbody>
```

Now i want to select each `( tbody > tr (with class="dataTR) > th )` elements, how could I do that using jQuery ? 
I've tried this way: `$('#tbodyCreateExpense .dataTR').find("th")` 
or `$('#tbodyCreateExpense .dataTR')[0].find("th")` (this way seems to work only when i have only 1 th below) but all of them didnt work.

Hope you guys can help, thanks so much in advanced !

Comment: `$('#tbodyCreateExpense .dataTR').find("th")` is spot on.  It will return an array of jQuery objects that match.

Comment: Don't you want to use TDs at some point???

Comment: You should use `TD` elements, not `TH` to display table datas, not headers. Even it works, you should use accurate markup

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('tbody tr.dataTR th');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Yru9/)**

for iterating over matched elements:

```
$('tbody tr.dataTR th').each(function(){
   //code here
});
```